# Add and divide color in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, math, colors

I would like to generate a middle color from two colors:

```
Color Middle = Color.FromRGB(Color.FromRgb( Color1.R + Color2.R) / 2, (Color1.G + Color2.G) / 2, (Color1.B + Color2.B) / (2);
```

This code won't compile because `FromRGB()` needs a `byte`.

So I tried this:

```
Color myColorMiddle = Color.FromRgb((byte)(Color1.R + Color2.R) / (byte)2, (byte)(Color1.G + Color2.G) / (byte)2, (byte)(Color1.B + Color2.B) / (byte)2);
```

But I get the same error. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arithmetic operations on byte (and short) yield an int result.  You have to put the entire expression in parentheses and cast that:

```
Color myColorMiddle = Color.FromRgb((byte)((Color1.R + Color2.R) / 2), (byte)((Color1.G + Color2.G) / 2), (byte)((Color1.B + Color2.B) / 2));
```

Your code will be cleaner if you extract this to a function:

```
byte Average(byte a, byte b)
{
    return (byte)((a + b) / 2);
}
```

Then your code looks like this:

```
Color myColorMiddle = Color.FromRgb(Average(Color1.R, Color2.R), Average(Color1.G, Color2.G), Average(Color1.B, Color2.B));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using System.Windows.Media.Color, I think you can do this:

```
  Color start = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
  Color end = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);
  Color middle = start + (end - start) * 0.5F;
```

Note, I did not try this, but I did get it from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.aspx

UPDATE

I have tested my most recent edit and it does work.

Comment: +1, learn something new every day.  I added some missing parentheses for you.